# Tinymce get changed content

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, codemirror

I'm using TinyMCE as a wysiwyg editor for a collaboration editor I'm working on.  I need very granular changes that are made to the editor(Insert('a'), Delete(2), etc.).  I see TinyMCE has a few events to handle this case, `onchange_callback`, and `handle_event_callback`.  Neither one of these methods give you what changed to the editor, just the editor instance or the event.  Is anyone aware of a method to just get changes to the editor, kind of like CodeMirror?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you can save the editor content at a specified point of time and then compare it to the editor content to a later time.